# Merge SAS datasets but keep only the common observations

Tags: merge, sas, dataset

Homework problem. Here are the questions:

a.   Merge **product_list** and **supplier** by
   *Supplier_ID* to create a new data set, **work.prodsup**.

b.   Submit the program and confirm that work.prodsup was created with 556
   observations.

c.   Modify the DATA step to output only those
   observations that are in **product_list** but not **supplier**.

Part A and B are done but part C is what I'm having trouble with.

Had to sort product_list first

```
proc sort data=hw2.product_list;
   by Supplier_ID;
run;

data work.prodsup;
   merge hw2.product_list hw2.supplier;
   by Supplier_ID;
run;
```

What is the function to modify output so that it only includes observations that in one dataset but not the other?

Answer (score 2):

You can add selection criteria by adding in=X into your merge statement:

```
data work.prodsup;
    merge hw2.product_list(in=a) hw2.supplier(in=b);
    by Supplier_ID;
    if a and not b;
run;
```

This is what you want, but you can also do neat tricks like left joins faster than in **proc sql**.

```
if a; /*Left join*/
if a and b; /*Inner join*/
if b; /*Right join*/
```

See more on merge in statement here: https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat481/node/18